# Angular2 CORS error when being redirected from API to Identityserver

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, cors, identityserver4

I have an `Angular2` application (runs on `localhost:3003`) that talks to a .net core web API (runs on `localhost:5432`) and an IdentityServer (runs on `localhost:5555`). I've enabled CORS in the API and the IdentityServer respectively by adding the following to their Configure method in the Startup class:

```
app.UseCors(builder => {
  builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

This fixed the problem I initially had getting the Angular2 app to talk to the identityserver over xhr.
However, I've now protected the API with the `[Authorize]` attribute so its going to redirect non-authenticated xhr requests to the identityserver and also if I supply a access token in my xhr request it will need to validate this with identityserver. However, this is giving me a CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5432/api/data. Redirect
>   from 'http://localhost:5432/api/data' to
>   'http://localhost:5555/connect/authorize?client_id=blahblahblah' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is
>   disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

Looking at the network trace, I can see the pre-flight CORS request being made and succeeding (with a `204` response), but the actual request for data that contains my access token is getting a `302` response and the above error.

Anyone have any suggestions on what I need to set (and where/what application) to fix this issue?

Comment: workaround for CORS problems is oftenly using a reverse proxy in dev like in production. You can achieve it by using the https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options that is natively integrated to Angular-cli : `ng serve --proxy proxy.conf.json` (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#proxy-to-backend)

Answer (score 0):

The API Resource doesn't need to *redirect* to the Authorization server.

Firstly, the Angular app should request an access_token from the Authorization server. The request will come back to Angular site.

Then, the Angular site makes a call to the API Resource with the access_token. The API Resource will validate the token with the authority (IdentityServer) but there's no redirection. If an access_token is not sent, then the API server would give a 401 Unauthorised response.

I don't believe CORS is needed on the Identity Server at all. Maybe there's another reason for that or maybe I am missing something in the scenario above.